# VSTS REST API for C# - How to get ALL (not first 250) pull requests that merge a commit Id?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the below API and method to try and get all PR commits that merge a given commitId. But the API only returns a max of 250. Is there a parameter or pagination technique to get the remaining?

```
 public void GetAllPullRequestsForCommit(Guid repoId, string commitId)
        {
            var query = new GitPullRequestQuery();
            var input = new GitPullRequestQueryInput() { Type = GitPullRequestQueryType.Commit, Items = new List<string>() { commitId } };

            query.QueryInputs = new List<GitPullRequestQueryInput>() { input };
            var response = _gitClient.GetPullRequestQueryAsync(query, repoId).Result;
        }
```

Comment: Do you see a continuation token in the response anywhere?

Comment: nope, there isn't any.